# Java script get root element by recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, recursion

I need to get the root element for each node.
I have two functions below.
When I ran `getRoot` I got `undefined`.
I think the problem is in the recursion function.

ex: for node `id=3`, I need `{id: 1, name: "Business1"}`.

```
//to get the parent for any node
function getParent(id) {
  const node = this._items.find(
    item => item.parent !== undefined && item.id == id
  );
  return node.parent;
}

//to get the root for the node
function getRoot(parent) {
  console.log(this._items);
  this._items.forEach(element => {
    if (element.id == parent) {
      if (element.parent === undefined) return element;
      else return this.getRoot(element.parent);
    }
  });
}
```

```
//constant array
const array = [
  {id: 1, name: "Business1"},
  {id: 2, name: "Canton1", parent: 1},
  {id: 3, name: "Branch1", parent: 2},
  {id: 4, name: "Branch2", parent: 2},
  {id: 5, name: "Canton2", parent: 1},
  {id: 6, name: "Branch1", parent: 5},
  {id: 7, name: "Branch2", parent: 5},
  {id: 8, name: "Canton3", parent: 1},
  {id: 9, name: "Branch1", parent: 8},
  {id: 10, name: "Branch2", parent: 8},
  {id: 9, name: "Business2"},
  {id: 10, name: "Canton1", parent: 9},
  {id: 11, name: "Branch1", parent: 10},
  {id: 12, name: "Branch2", parent: 10},
  {id: 13, name: "Canton2", parent: 9},
  {id: 14, name: "Branch1", parent: 13},
  {id: 15, name: "Branch2", parent: 13},
  {id: 16, name: "Canton3", parent: 9},
  {id: 17, name: "Branch1", parent: 16},
  {id: 18, name: "Branch2", parent: 16},
];
```

Comment: There are two `id: 9` and `id: 10` in the `array`.  Which ones did you want?  May I suggest you edit the `array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let _items = [
    {id: 1, name: "Business1"},
    {id: 2, name: "Canton1", parent: 1},
    {id: 3, name: "Branch1", parent: 2},
    {id: 4, name: "Branch2", parent: 2},
    {id: 5, name: "Canton2", parent: 1},
    {id: 6, name: "Branch1", parent: 5},
    {id: 7, name: "Branch2", parent: 5},
    {id: 8, name: "Canton3", parent: 1},
    {id: 9, name: "Branch1", parent: 8},
    {id: 10, name: "Branch2", parent: 8},
    {id: 11, name: "Business2"},
    {id: 12, name: "Canton1", parent: 11},
    {id: 13, name: "Branch1", parent: 12},
    {id: 14, name: "Branch2", parent: 12},
    {id: 15, name: "Canton2", parent: 11},
    {id: 16, name: "Branch1", parent: 15},
    {id: 17, name: "Branch2", parent: 15},
    {id: 18, name: "Canton3", parent: 11},
    {id: 19, name: "Branch1", parent: 18},
    {id: 20, name: "Branch2", parent: 18}
];
function findElementById(id) {
    let element_return = false;
    _items.forEach(element => {
        if (id === element.id) {
            element_return = element;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return element_return;
}
function getRoot(parent) {
    element = findElementById(parent);
    if (element) {
        if (typeof (element.parent) !== "undefined") {
            return getRoot(element.parent);
        } else {
            return element.id;
        }
    } else {
        return parent;
    }
}
let test_root = getRoot(3);
console.log(test_root);
console.log(findElementById(test_root));

test_root = getRoot(11);
console.log(test_root);
console.log(findElementById(test_root));
```

Comment: thank you dear,but not always i need return {id: 1, name: "Business1"},
for id =11, i need { id: 9, name: "Business2" },  @angel.bonev

Comment: @Alaa I've added 11 as a test and it returns `{ id: 9, name: "Business2" }`

Comment: @Alaa but you have twice id: 10 my approach is to follow first found element, you will have the same issue with 13

Comment: sorry dear,the id is sequence from 1 to 20 @angel.bonev

Comment: @Alaa can you update your question with the right input data ?

Comment: @Alaa input data is changed check it now

Answer (score 2):

```js
const items = [{ id: 1, name: "Business1" },
{ id: 2, name: "Canton1", parent: 1 },
{ id: 3, name: "Branch1", parent: 2 },
{ id: 4, name: "Branch2", parent: 2 },
{ id: 5, name: "Canton2", parent: 1 },
{ id: 6, name: "Branch1", parent: 5 },
{ id: 7, name: "Branch2", parent: 5 },
{ id: 8, name: "Canton3", parent: 1 },
{ id: 9, name: "Branch1", parent: 8 },
{ id: 10, name: "Branch2", parent: 8 },
{ id: 9, name: "Business2" },
{ id: 10, name: "Canton1", parent: 9 },
{ id: 11, name: "Branch1", parent: 10 },
{ id: 12, name: "Branch2", parent: 10 },
{ id: 13, name: "Canton2", parent: 9 },
{ id: 14, name: "Branch1", parent: 13 },
{ id: 15, name: "Branch2", parent: 13 },
{ id: 16, name: "Canton3", parent: 9 },
{ id: 17, name: "Branch1", parent: 16 },
{ id: 18, name: "Branch2", parent: 16 }]


const getParent = (id) => {
    const node = items.filter(e => e.id == id)
    if (node.length == 0) return undefined // throw some error here
    let currentNode = node[0]
    return currentNode.parent !== undefined ? getParent(currentNode.parent) : currentNode
}

console.log(getParent(3))
```

Comment: thank you dear,but for id =11, i  need  { id: 9, name: "Business2" },    @Naor Tedgi

Comment: node 10 appear twice Branch2 and Canton1 what is the strategy in this case ? you can go 11->10->8->1 and also 11->10->9

Comment: for all nodes from 10 to 18 their parent is { id: 9, name: "Business2" } @Naor Tedgi

Comment: look at the data again please     {id: 10, name: "Branch2", parent: 8},
and { id: 10, name: "Canton1", parent: 9 }, same node 2 different parents

Comment: sorry dear,the id is sequence from 1 to 20 @Naor Tedgi

Comment: the id is the *index of the element inside the array* ?? or the property *id* inside the json?

Comment: the id is one  of object elements (id,name,parent)
{ id: 9, name: "Business2" } is { id: 10, name: "Business2" }    @Naor Tedgi

Comment: @NaorTedgi change `if (node.length == 0) return undefined` to `if (node.length !== 1) return undefined`  and it will work for a broken struct LOL .  nice approach btw

Comment: LOL yes it can solve it ,  but it isn't the use case Alaa wants I think there is a misunderstanding about the index

Comment: Alaa can you please  add to your question the path from node 11 to is parent .